# Application partially closes during User Sign Off

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

I have an application that seems to only partially close when a user requests to log off or shutdown.

When a user selects log off or shutdown, Windows prompts the user with the option of force closing the application or canceling and returning to the application to save and close. This behavior is correct, however if the user selects to cancel the log off, the application is closed anyway with a return code 0.

The application should stay fully open allowing the user to return to the application and save their work before shutting down.

I'm not necessarily looking for the solution here as I don't quite understand the problem. I'm mainly looking for how to go about debugging this. Questions/Problems I have:

- How does windows command the application to shutdown?
- How can I prevent the application from starting the cleanup process before the user selects to actually close applications?
- Visual studio's debugger also goes down during this process which makes it challenging to catch what's going on.

This issue also proves challenging to google as the terms are very generic and comes up with general Windows OS troubleshooting.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're handling `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` / `WM_ENDSESSION` and call `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()` / `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy()` to borrow time to clean up

Answer (score 0):

Using taskkill allowed me to debug how the application responds to the shutdown signals.

Other solutions and answers for debugging similar issues can be found here: https://superuser.com/questions/959364/on-windows-how-can-i-gracefully-ask-a-running-program-to-terminate